# Unable to make an element's position sticky in a mat-drawer-container

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-drawer

I'm having a problem with a `div` using `position: sticky;` inside `mat-drawer-container`. Here's what I've tried:

```css
.mat-drawer-container.my-drawer-container {
    overflow: scroll;
}

.mat-drawer-content.my-drawer-content {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

with no luck :(

Any thoughts?

This doesn't work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqk1oj-pg4xq8

This works (the desired result)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqk1oj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the class names used in the template and styles do not match. Once that is corrected you will see that `overflow: scroll` undesirably gives two scrollbars within the container.

The default value for the `overflow` property in the `mat-drawer-container` and `mat-drawer-content` classes is `hidden`. When `overflow: hidden` is set to any ancestor of a sticky element, the ancestor element will become the scrolling container. To avoid this, simply `unset` the `overflow` property.

```css
.mat-drawer-container.my-mat-drawer-container {
    overflow: unset;
}

.mat-drawer-content.my-mat-drawer-content {
    overflow: unset;
}
```

The `div` will now be `sticky`.